# Full Screen in React Native - Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, native, react-native-video

I want to make a specific screen that occupies the full-screen. I have a `react-native-video` player with custom styles, as seen in the "basic" example at the following link
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/tree/master/examples/basic

But I can't do the full screen with custom styles. I implemented a modal to simulate the full screen as seen in the image:

[image: My component code for get full screen in modal]

And also activate `StatusBar.setHidden` (true) but I can't disappear the navigation buttons in Android

[image: Video testing with modal and hidden status bar]

I tried installing the `react-native-full-screen` library but it didn't remove the navigation buttons.

Maybe someone comes up with a solution.

I'm using

- "react": "16.9.0",
- "react-native": "0.61.5",
- "react-native-navigation": "6.4.0",
- "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",